# Google Analytics not getting number for email tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have done all the pre work of generating tracking ID and am trying to add email tracking to my HTML email template. I have added

```
<img src="http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-12345678-1&cid=CLIENT_ID_NUMBER&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&cm=email&cn=Campaign_Name" />
```

to the bottom of the template. GA is not collecting any numbers when i open this email in any email client. Gmail removes the src tag completely when it loads images. What am i missing?

Comment: Just including that "link" in the source won't do anything. What are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to track clicks on email links, have you tried the URL builder to tag the links with UTM parameters?

Comment: I am trying to track email opens. This is based on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email)

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for clarifying. Are you using an actual client ID number or that placeholder string? Also, are you observing in Real-time reports as well for your event?

Comment: Yes, all actual numbers. I dont see anything firing anywhere within GA. Gmail removes the src attribute from the img tag completely!

Comment: It might be related to this: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41275/how-do-i-avoid-the-img-src-attribute-being-stripped-by-gmail

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking! It is actually not.

I got the [Google Analytics Chrome Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and opened the email in an Incognito Window. Both Gmail and Yahoo then got the src attribute and the debugger showed **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

There was an issue with extra spaces that got in as a result of line breaks and indentation. There was a %20 inserted for each space, which could not be resolved. I got rid of the extra spaces and it fixed everything.